# Archive Manager - Password error

Tags: archive

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Archive Manager 3.16.5

I believe I have uncovered an error with Archive Manager. I do not know where to report errors so I am reporting it here. Perhaps some kind sole can verify it is an error and let me know where to properly report it.

1. From Files, right-click on a single file and select context menu item "Compress...".
2. Modify the archive filename as desired. Select archive type .zip. Do not specify a password. Click the "Create" button.
3. Open the newly created archive and delete the single file it contains.
4. Select Archive manager menu item Edit > Set Password...
5. Enter the desired password and click the "Save" button. At this point a dialog appears with the following error message:

   **Could not create the archive**

   Error when getting information for file '/home/John/Documents/Personal/.fr-Gr7BGf/junk.zip': No such file or directory

The file '/home/John/Documents/Personal/junk.zip' does exist and is open. The "/.fr-Gr7BGf" part has been mistakenly put into the file path resulting in the error message. (The password did not contain "/.fr-Gr7BGf".)

I realize it is not common to ask for a password protected archive with no contents. But to me this error indicates a string over running its intended memory which should probably be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

To find out how report a bug read [Reporting Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). Follow the process described under [Reporting non-crash hardware and desktop application bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Reporting_non-crash_hardware_and_desktop_application_bugs). You will need a [Launchpad account](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/NewAccount).